# Why Would Uncle Vernon Be Proud?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ... "It is not for you to decide what the Ministry of Magic does or does not do, Dumbledore!" snapped Fudge, now a shade of magenta of which Uncle Vernon would have been proud. ...
> [*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* page 147]

Why would Uncle Vernon be proud of other people going magenta in the face? Or does it have another meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncle Vernon is depicted as an always angry, red in the face, yelling and screaming man.

> snapped Fudge

Cornelius Fudge responded with a snap, meaning to be blunt, quick, and sometimes means in a rude way.

> now a shade of magenta

his face has turned magenta because looking at the context of what he said, and how he said it, he is clearly angry. some people, when angry, get red in the face.
Uncle Vernon was a man who often times got red in the face with anger, just like fudge is doing. this is making a reference to another angry man, and even implying that fudge is maybe more red, more angry than vernon gets.

> of which Uncle Vernon would have been proud.

Uncle Vernon the character might not be actually proud, this more just a reference to Uncle Vernon and possibly implying fudge in this moment surpasses Uncle Vernon's normal level of rage. Implying fudges rage would impress Vernon because it is more than his own.

these kind of comparisons are normally just that, a comparison. comparing the way Vernon is and how upset Fudge is. Giving the reader a reference to something that has a similar description.

Comment: Nice answer, and ninja'd me

Answer (score 0):

When some people get angry they get red, or "magenta" faces.  Uncle Vernon gets red-faced when he is angry.

Then there is an idiom "of which {someone} would be proud".  (or "would make {someone} proud") It can be used either in a fairly direct way.  "This is a tower of which Eiffel would be proud."  Or humorously - here it is used as a joke. The joke is the ridiculous idea that Vernon wants to be red-in-the-face.

So overall it means that Fudge is getting angry and getting a purple-red face that is as bright as the ones that Uncle Vernon gets.